# configuring default PYTHONPATH

Tags: python, django, configuration

I have Django application and few Django commands that I would execute through cronjobs on CentOS 5.

Recently I updated my `python-setuptools` package, which in-turn update `python-devel` packages.

After performing this update, the default `PYTHONPATH` settings for the Django commands executed through cronjob are different from the Django application which I execute from shell. Because of this mismatch my old Django cronjobs fail since the required libraries are not in path.

How do I resolve this issue and ensure that both the cronjob Django commands and the Django application have the same environment?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue.

When i had updated my python-setuptools and python-devel packages the default python interpreter configuration changed to the new updated version which has libraries in a different place compared to my old python interpreter.

This affected only the default python interpreter executed from the cronjob, i used absolute path of the old python interpreter in my cronjob scripts and the issue was resolved.

thanks
Shan